# Spark Override Accumulator

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I cannot seem to find any examples of a way to override a Spark Accumulator. I have data in a key/value format with the key being the column index. My function below filters out things that are not digits. My goal is to track how many empties per column are found.

I have the following filter:

```
val numFilterRDD = numRDD.filter(filterNum)

    def isAllDigits(x: String) = x matches """^\d{1,}\.*\d*$"""
    def filterNum(x: (Int, String)) : Boolean = {
      accumNum.add(1)
      if(isAllDigits(x._2)) true
      else false
    }
```

Right now the solution is too passes, I need to do the following before the filter:

```
val originalCountNum = numRDD.map(x => (x._1, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).collect()
```

And finally a comparison of the two. Is this possible with accumulators to be able to track column index + empty count, it would remove the additional pass of the original count.

Comment: Just a note. Instead of `if(isAllDigits(x._2)) true else false` it would be enough to simply use `isAllDigits(x._2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use custom `AccumulatorParam`. For example you can use map like this:

```
object CountPairsParam extends AccumulatorParam[Map[Int, Int]] {

  def zero(initialValue: Map[Int, Int]): Map[Int, Int] = {
    Map.empty[Int, Int]
  }

  def addInPlace(m1: Map[Int, Int], m2: Map[Int, Int]): Map[Int, Int] = {
    val keys = m1.keys ++ m2.keys
    keys.map((k: Int) => (k -> (m1.getOrElse(k, 0) + m2.getOrElse(k, 0)))).toMap
  }
}

val rdd = sc.parallelize(List((1, -1), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, -1), (2, 0)))
val accum = sc.accumulator(Map.empty[Int, Int])(CountPairsParam)
```

Inside filter you use do something like this:

```
val allDigits = isAllDigits(x._2)
if(allDigits) { 
    accum += Map(x._1 -> 1)
}
```